# Feasibility of DYI fix of IPDM in Nissan Juke

Tags: nissan, electronics, juke

I have Nissan Juke. Brake lights are not working. Pedal sensors are fine. Fuses appear fine. A mechanic noticed that the lights went on briefly when he was moving cords going into IPDM module:

[image]

Specifically 61, 62 ones:

[image]

which are described as "Ignition relay power
supply":

[image]

I would like to disconnect the module, like this:

[image]

And then open this box and see if there's anything obviously wrong inside, perhaps clean it up.

Is this a bad idea? I don't have any automotive experience.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!